# set v-show to true or false with a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of properties (houses, flats,...) that I render with Vue.

Each property is shown or not according to some buttons that act like filters. Those "filters" are set in my data object:

```
data: {
    properties: myPropertiesList,
    rooms: {
        1: false,
        2: false,
        3: false,
        4: false,
    },
    type: {
        flat: false,
        house: false,
        field: false
    }
},
```

I set those option to true or false when user click on the options buttons.

Currently, I set v-show with the current expression:

> v-show="rooms[property.Rooms] && type[property.Category]"

```
<div v-show="rooms[property.Rooms] && type[property.Category]" 
        class="col-md-3" 
        v-for="property in properties"
    >
        <property :property="property"> 
</div>
```

... And it works fine. However, I would rather like to do something like this:

> v-show="showProperty(property)"

... and write that *showProperty()* function that return true or false.

1. Is something like that possible ?
2. If it is, where do you declare the function ? I tried in the methods object but it doesn't work.

Comment: Never used Vue, but you could define a method on your data object, passing in the property.Rooms and property.Category, which would return a boolean. If you can't do that, you could write a function external from the data object, passing in the object, property.Rooms and property.Category, which would also return a boolean value based on your logic above.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of a filter as proposed by Jeff is the way to go, but I want to answer your immediate question weither this is *possible* with a function, because it is.

You simply add the function to the components methods object:

```
methods: {
  showProperty (property) {
    return this.rooms[property.Rooms] && this.type[property.Category]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a call for `v-for` filtering:

```
...
data:function(){
    properties:MyPropertyList,
    rooms: [1,2,3,4],
    types: ['flat','house','field']
},
...

<div v-for="property in properties | filterBy Room in rooms | filterBy Category in types" 
    class="col-md-3"
>
    <property :property="property"> 
</div>
```

This will only show properties if `property.Room` is in the `rooms` array, and `property.Category` is in the `types` array.

If you need the rooms and types in objects like you have them now, you can use a computed property to create the array for filtering.

```
computed:{
  roomList:function(){
    //go through the rooms object and return an array of the true ones
  }
}
```

If you want to filter with a custom function you can:

```
<div v-for="property in properties | filterBy showPropertyFilter rooms type">
```

And before all of this, create the filter:

```
Vue.filter('showPropertyFilter',function(properties, rooms, type){
    //return only the properties that should show
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't use filterBy, I think I'm limited by this feature. I need a more complex way to decide if the property element is shown or not. So my idea was to use v-show with a function and return true or false given the result of a few conditions in that function.

Comment: You can use filterBy with a custom function as well, see edit.

Comment: Here is a more in-depth post about creating a custom filter http://optimizely.github.io/vuejs.org/guide/filters.html